# How to Divide Cart items Based upon Attribute value

Tags: magento2, cart

I was trying to Divide Cart items Based on Attribute value. I tried to fetch the attribute on Cart Page.

Basically I have Attribute `is_ship_immediately` with yes or no option. I have products with yes or no options in the cart. If option is yes for products in cart then I want to show option yes items under the title(Ship immediately). Then If option is no I want to Show option no items under title(Not Ship immediately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change the cart item templates probably, depending on your design.

There you'll get a collection of the cart items. From the items you can fetch the product model using the `getProduct` method. Then finally you may call the `getData('is_ship_immediately')` on the product model to get your data, and then structure your cart accordingly.

A simple working example would be to change `Magento_Checkout::cart/form.phtml` at around line number **36** where this is written

```
<?php foreach ($block->getItems() as $_item): ?>
    <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

to this

```
<?php
    $cartItems = [
        'ship_immediately'      => [],
        'dont_ship_immediately' => []
    ];
    foreach ($block->getItems() as $_item) {
        if ($_item->getProduct()->getData("is_ship_immediately")) {
            $cartItems['ship_immediately'][] = $block->getItemHtml($_item);
        } else {
            $cartItems['dont_ship_immediately'][] = $block->getItemHtml($_item);
        }
    }
?>

<?php /* SHIP THESE ITEMS IMMEDIATELY!!! */ ?>
<tr><th><?= __("Ship immediately") ?></th></tr>
<?= implode("", $cartItems['ship_immediately']) ?>

<?php /* Meh...These can wait */ ?>
<tr><th><?= __("Don't ship immediately") ?></th></tr>
<?= implode("", $cartItems['dont_ship_immediately']) ?>
```

**NOTE**

DO NOT CHANGE THE TEMPLATE FILE DIRECTLY.

Override it in your theme or write an `afterPlugin` to the `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Grid` class's `getTemplate` function where you would return your own cart template, and then make the changes there

#### P.S

Since the product information may change, I'd suggest you keep the `is_ship_immediately` data on your `quote_item` as well as `order_item` level

Comment: Thank you with a bit of change in your code it worked for me.